# how to stop several sounds when I click on a button start again

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, soundpool

In my application I make a music background that works when click on a button start and the music changes loop sound1, sound2, sound3.

```
 public void startNewGame() {//initializing the sounds

   final  MediaPlayer sound1 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music1);

   final MediaPlayer sound2 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music2);

   final MediaPlayer sound3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music3);

    //generate random number
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;

    //picking the right sound to play
    switch (randomInt){
        case 1:
            if ( !sound1.isPlaying())
                sound1.setLooping(true);
              sound1.start();

            break;
        case 2:  if ( !sound2.isPlaying() )

                    sound2.setLooping(true);
                    sound2.start();

            break;
        case 3:  
                if ( !sound3.isPlaying() )
                sound3.setLooping(true);
                sound3.start();

           break;
    }

    mBtnChooseAndStart.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fl_board_container, 
   GameFragment.newInstance(mBitmapBricks, GOAL_STATUS))
                .commit();
    }
```

the pobelem is that when I click on another button start again that generates a dialogue after confirmation I start the game but with another sound that works and the first does not stop
how to solve this problem thanks in advance

```
 public void restart(View view) {

    if (mFullBitmap == null) {
        // Not started, so cannot restart
        UIUtils.toast(this, getString(R.string.not_started));
        return;
    }

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.restart))
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.confirm_restart_msg))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.confirm), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    startNewGame();
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.cancel), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

and also how to stop sounds in onBackpressed ().

Comment: `if (sound1 == null) ;` Those ifs are not doing what you think they're doing (in fact they're doing nothing). I suggest you review how ifs work in Java.

Comment: thank you for targeting me the error i try if (sound1 == null) {} but application stops .if you can offer me a solution

Comment: It seems that your problem is that you lack the basics of programming, you should try some simpler problems before attempting this.

Comment: I thought that the fact of trying to use this site is to have help if I encounter a difficulty to go ahead. not to orient me to redo java classes because I use one; and there are some examples of the same problem, and people try to give help, in my opinion the problem is not if it's the algorithm ... and instead of fading alone to solve my problem to find a solution I am gonna lose my time in no the base of the programming, no it is the algorithm. it is not you which will discourage me

Comment: I'm definitely not trying to discourage you, however this site is a Q&A site for very specific questions with very specific answers. Your question is way too broad to answer here since it involves lack of very basic concepts which are too long to explain here and are already covered by a lot of other resources available on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

finally I found the solution and it works
firstly create a method to stop mediaplayer

```
public void cleanUpMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null) {
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mediaPlayer.stop();
        }
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
}
```

then create a method of launching for each sound and within this method it is necessary to apply the functin to stop mediaplayer if it exist

```
public void sound1(){
    cleanUpMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music1);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void sound2(){
    cleanUpMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music2);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}

public void sound3(){
    cleanUpMediaPlayer();
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.music3);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);
    mediaPlayer.start();
}
```

finally call the sounds in the desired moment
for me I want the sounds to change every time I play my game that's why I use random with switch loop like this.

```
 Random randomGenerator = new Random();
    int randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(3) + 1;

    //picking the right sound to play
    switch (randomInt){
        case 1:
           sound1();

            break;
        case 2:
            sound2();

            break;
        case 3:
            sound3();

            break;

    }
```

the same for onBackPressed() you just have to call cleanUpMediaPlayer method

```
public void onBackPressed() {

 cleanUpMediaPlayer();
```

.....
}

a good day for my friend mistek :)